# Error when instantiating a new excel process

Tags: c#, .net, excel, automation, com+

This problem is related to my previous question at [Maximum number of excel processes?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11158971/maximum-number-of-excel-processes/11159413#11159413), but with different behavior.

In short: there is a COM+ component that opens a number of excel processes when it's started. The handles are added to a list, so they don't get out of scope or garbage collected.

If I run this component locally (windows 7 64 bit, 12 Gb of memory), it starts fine and it opens 30 excel processes without a problem.

If I run this component on a (virtual) server (windows server 2003 R2 SP2 64 bit, 4 Gb), then the first 21 excel processes are started correctly, but the remaining 9 processes are not created; and in the event log I see 9 times the following error:

```
 Retrieving the COM class factory for component with CLSID {00024500-0000-0000-C000-000000000046} failed due to the following error: 80080005.
```

So creating the last 9 excel processes result in exceptions, it seems to hit a limit of 21 excel processes.

If I try it on yet another server (Windows Server 2003 SP 2, 1 Gb RAM), it creates 22 excel processes, and 8 that fail with the same exception.

I'm wondering what is causing the excel process creation to fail on these servers?

EDIT: I can open 30 excel instances without problem if I manually open them using the start menu.

Any ideas?

Thanks,
L

Comment: but just wondering why would u want that many processes?

Comment: it's a server that processes calculations, and in order to 'cache' calculations we want most of them in memory (loading them each time takes too much time)

Comment: Similar error found here with a few options to try: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/881132/retrieving-the-com-class-factory-for-component-failed

Comment: Is this page relevant for you: http://blogs.msdn.com/b/adioltean/archive/2005/06/24/432519.aspx?

Comment: I doubt it, because it consistently happens after 21 excel instances... it seems that it has nothing to do with heavy load.

Answer (score 0):

Technically what you are doing isn't supported at all:
http://support.microsoft.com/kb/257757

> Microsoft does not currently recommend, and does not support,
>   Automation of Microsoft Office applications from any unattended,
>   non-interactive client application or component (including ASP,
>   ASP.NET, DCOM, and NT Services), because Office may exhibit unstable
>   behavior and/or deadlock when Office is run in this environment.

That said, because of the slight inconsistencies between servers, I beleive you are running into some sort of a resource conflict/limitation and not something specific to excel.  With the limited amount of memory on the server, it could be simply running out of or fragmenting memory.

Comment: I know it's not supported, but it's legacy code that needs to be supported, so for now I can't change it to for example Excel Services. Concerning memory: how is it possible that on 1 gig it can create 22 instances and on 4 gig only 21? And I can open more that 25 excel files manually...

Comment: These might be better comments for your original question but: What version of excel is this?  Is it 32 or 64 bit?  Is your process 32 or 64 bit?